# WinSock: Check if transfered file is complete

Tags: visual-c++, winsock, file-transfer

I'm planning to make a file transport using sockets(TCP) on Windows with C++. Hence it would be quite convenient to see if the transferred file has been received completely and correctly. What would be the best (and maybe also the easiest) way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after all of the Bytes are sent everything has been received correctly - TCP will ensure that : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Do not try to re-calculate checksums of individual packets or something, you will introduce errors. TCP is *somewhat* reliable, every transfer is automatically segmented, padded with checksums, reassembled and checked for a matching checksum - thats a pretty reliable transport protocol right there, it will work out-of-the-box

If you're **really** paranoid or simply need to create digital proof of transmission you need to choose another protocol entirely - something like [SCTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol), perhaps